# Material-UI withStyles not adding classes to props

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to implement some styling using Material-UI's `withStyles` method, however I'm not able to get classes as a prop. Any suggestions as to what I'm missing? I've included the relevant code below, but note that there is an `<App>` component in this file that I'm leaving out for brevity.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {Paper, Typography} from '@material-ui/core'
import {withStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import NavBar from "./navBar";

class Recipe extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('Recipe Did Mount')
    }

    render() {
        const {recipeData, classes} = this.props;
        return (
            <Paper>
                <Typography className={classes.recipeName}>{recipeData.name}</Typography>
                <Typography className={classes.recipeIngredients}>{recipeData.ingredients}</Typography>
                <Typography className={classes.recipeInstructions}>{recipeData.instructions}</Typography>
            </Paper>
        )
    }
}

const styles = {
    root: {
        fontSize: "1.0rem",
        margin: "0px"
    },
    recipeName: {
        fontSize: "1.0rem",
        margin: "0px"
    },
    recipeIngredients: {
        fontSize: "1.0rem",
        margin: "0px"    },
    recipeInstructions: {
        fontSize: "1.0rem",
        margin: "0px"    }
};

withStyles(styles)(Recipe);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <App/>,
        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')),
    )
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you aren't setting `withStyles(styles)(Recipe);` into a variable, I suspect you must be using `Recipe` directly within `App`.

`withStyles` doesn't change `Recipe`. `withStyles` creates a new component that wraps `Recipe` and passes the `classes` prop to it. In order to see the `classes` prop, you need to use the newly-created component with something like the following:

```
const StyledRecipe = withStyles(styles)(Recipe);
const App = ()=> {
   return <StyledRecipe/>;
}
```

Comment: I believe this is the issue.I will implement this solution and mark this as the solution if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming App is defined in a separate file (for others who may come looking for this question), change the

```
`withStyles(styles)(Recipe);`
```

To

```
export default withStyles(styles)(Recipe);
```

As Ryan already explained ' withStyles is the higher order component that creates and returns a new component'